# Omitted Variables because of collinearity

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, econometrics, multicollinearity

```
memb            float   %9.0g                 proportion of permanent employees who are
                                                members of the worker cooperative
bonus           float   %9.0g                 average distributed profits per worker in
                                                millions of lire

. reg lnQ lnL lnK memb own lnBonus
note: memb omitted because of collinearity
note: lnBonus omitted because of collinearity

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =       4
-------------+------------------------------           F(  3,     0) =       .
       Model |    2.353812     3  .784603999           Prob > F      =       .
    Residual |           0     0           .           R-squared     =  1.0000
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =       .
       Total |    2.353812     3  .784603999           Root MSE      =       0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         lnQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lnL |   .4852686          .        .       .            .           .
         lnK |   .4817975          .        .       .            .           .
        memb |          0  (omitted)
         own |   .0133421          .        .       .            .           .
     lnBonus |          0  (omitted)
       _cons |   2.260949          .        .       .            .           .
```

when I run a regression, memb and InBonud are omitted. I know it says because of collinearity....However, based on the description for both variables , I do not see how they relate to each other. Does anyone have an explanation why memb and InBonus are omitted?

Comment: you have 4 observations and 5 variables....you'll notice that nothing is really working in the regression above: you just have too few observations.

Comment: even InBonus have only four observations, what is the reasons why they are omiited ?

Comment: You can't fit a regression where the number of parameters exceeds the number of observations. The X'X matrix is not invertible then. Think about fitting a line through a single point $(y,x)$. You can't even fit a constant since there's an infinite number of equations $y = mx+b$ that pass through that point.

Comment: what if I have four variables and 4 observations for Inbonus?

Comment: It's the same. With 4 variables and 4 observations, you will describe any relationship perfectly. The $R^2$ will be 1. When you go to add the fifth variable, any subset of 4 variables will fit the data equally well. There's no way to choose, so it does not matter which one you drop (though it will influence the coefficients). Another fancy word for multicollinearity is micronumerosity: not enough data.

Comment: so this is the reason why the software drop two of my variables...My next question is if three variables and four observations for InBonus, this works then right?

Comment: the only prescription is more cowbell! uh... observations, I mean

Comment: WHAT DO YOU MEAN?

Comment: A *non-rigorous* rule of thumb is that you should have about 10-20 observation for every predictor you want to include in a linear model for it to be reliable (not overfit).

Comment: To fit this model you would need at least 40 rows of data. It won't work right with 4 observations, even with only 1 independent variable

Comment: Slight correction to my comment above: With $n$ variables and $n$ observations, you will describe any relationship perfectly as long as no observation has the same $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, because you've got 4 observations!

Thus you can only estimate 4 distinct quantities. (Notice how many coefficients are non-zero.)

Comment: even InBonus have only four observations, what is the reasons why they are omiited ?

Comment: I'm not sure why the software chose those two to omit - it could have just as easily omitted 'own'. Try removing the constant (_cons) and I guarantee you there will be one less 0. Can you help me understand why you only have 4 rows of data?

Comment: what are u referring to?